# How to determine the angle for constructive interference of incoherent light in Young's double slit experiment?

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I understand that we would need to consider the phase difference to answer this question but I am unsure of how to do so.

Comment: derivation about 1/3 the way down this https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/27-3-youngs-double-slit-experiment/  See Figure 5

Comment: @JohnHunter this is only the derivation for coherent light that is in phase I was looking for light that is not in phase as they leave the slits